# SHA 512 and or ARGON2ID Hashing + Salt For Dovecot in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0, dovecot

I have tried to generate a salted hash using ARGON2ID and am running in to the same issues. The dovecot password generation utility generates the correct hash but I still cant seem to get things working using C#.

I am using the Konscious.Security.Cryptography.Argon2 Nuget Package at the moment..

Like I said still doesn't work even after playing with the length of the salt
I setup a new mail-server using postfix and dovecot. The password storage I am using is SSHA512 which means SHA512 with a salt. I need to create an ASP.NET page that allows the user to create and change their e-mail password in the DB. I could use the SQL route but I would like to do this in C# so I can use NHibernate which is my ORM.

I found a post online that creates the hash and salt using SQL.

INSERT INTO `virtual_users`
(`id`, `domain_id`, `password` , `email`)
VALUES
(NULL, '1',  (SELECT REPLACE(TO_BASE64(CONCAT(UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT('YourPasswordHere', v.salt), 512)), v.salt)), '\n', '') AS salted FROM (SELECT SHA2(RAND(), 512) AS salt) v), 'user@example.com');

UPDATE virtual_users
SET `password` = (
SELECT REPLACE(TO_BASE64(CONCAT(UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT('YourPasswordHere', v.salt), 512)), v.salt)), '\n', '') AS salted
FROM (
SELECT SHA2(RAND(), 512) AS salt
) v
)
WHERE email = 'user@example.com';

Here is an explanation of what is going on. I am trying to do the following in C# and am not having any luck..

1. Generate a random (rather lengthy) salt
2. Append the salt to the password
3. Get the SHA512 Hash of #2
4. Convert the hash to binary
5. Append the salt to #4
6. Convert the whole thing to Base64

7 .Remove unwanted newlines added by MySQL's TO_BASE64() function

The result is a 256 byte long string so you may need to update your password field to VARCHAR(256).

Any instruction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work

SH1512 Code:

```
//My Random Method
public byte[] GenerateRandomCryptographicBytes(int keyLength)
{
    var randomBytes = new byte[keyLength];
    var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    return randomBytes;
}

//Hashing Method:
public PasswordHashResult HashWithSalt(string password, int saltLength, HashAlgorithm  hashAlgo)
{
    var rng = new Rng();
    var saltBytes = rng.GenerateRandomCryptographicBytes(saltLength);
    var passwordAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    var passwordWithSaltBytes = new List<byte>();
    passwordWithSaltBytes.AddRange(passwordAsBytes);
    passwordWithSaltBytes.AddRange(saltBytes);
    var digestBytes = hashAlgo.ComputeHash(passwordWithSaltBytes.ToArray());


    return new PasswordHashResult
    {
        Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes),
        PasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(digestBytes)
    };
}

//Result Class:
public sealed class PasswordHashResult
{
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string HashAndSalt { get; set; }
}
```

---

Argon2 Code:

```
 public byte[] CreateHash(byte[] password, byte[] salt)
{
    using var argon2 = new Argon2id(password);
    argon2.Salt = salt;
    argon2.DegreeOfParallelism = 8;
    argon2.Iterations = 4;
    argon2.MemorySize = 1024 * 128;

    return argon2.GetBytes(32);
}

public static byte[] GenerateRandomCryptographicBytes()
{
    var randomBytes = new byte[32];
    var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    return randomBytes;
}

 var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextPassword);
    var salt = PasswordService.GenerateRandomCryptographicBytes();     // Salt should be stored alongside hash.
    var hash = passwordService.CreateHash(bytes, salt);
```

Here is what the Argon2id hash looks like.
{ARGON2ID}$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=1$UCLtz5ubAeKTzeIVo0pzPw$jDDq5JmNX9LRzmlzknJWsGYKJ0TLiEHG6MGt5jcp6XQ

Nothing Like What I Get returned from the code above.

Comment: This seems to be somewhat helpful https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-08-17-php72-argon2-hash-password.html

Comment: One thing I can tell you for sure is that Dovecot implementation of Argon2 is very specific. No = signs in the salt or hash or it will mismatch.